# Access the database connection data, in Symfony

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, symfony

I'm kinda new in Symfony, and I'm having this problem. I want to access the database connection data, in in **app/config/parameters.yml**, this is a php file locate in **src/Myproject/MyBundle/Resources/public/query.php**. This just to run a query. If I run this code its works, but I  want something safer.

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$link) {
   die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('database2', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
   die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Do you want to change in runtime the database you connect to or just want to get the configuration information from parameters.yml?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to define your queries inside RESOURCES folder; that's out of Symfony commision; You need to define entities and do your queries inside a controller or EntityRepository

Comment: Hi, I know its not the standard way to run queries, but I have a jquey script inside my project that points to that file and runs it. If I point it a controller, repository file, it doesn't work. So this is best way, I've found.

Comment: Do you mind if you put your jQuery script (at least the section you point to this php file)?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
        // ajax setup
        $.ajaxSetup({
            url: '{{ asset('bundles/myproject/query.php') }}',
            type: 'POST',
            cache: 'false'
        });

Comment: I just want do get the vars database_host, database_pass, database_user, from paramenters.yml, in that file. Isn't there a way something like **$this->container->getParameter('database_host')**

Comment: @Liam yes there is but you need to be in controller or a service to call. I provided an answer and hopefully it helps

Comment: Modify your javascript!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is to create a routing and proper action in your controller for your Ajax url then you won't need to create the php file in Resources folder

1) Generate a routing for your Ajax

```
mybundle_ajaxrequest:
   pattern: /ajaxcheck
   defaults: { _controller: myBundle:Default:ajaxCheck }
```

2) Create a proper action in Default controller and put all your back-end code inside

```
public function ajaxCheckAction() {
   $host_name = $this->container->getParameter('database_host');
   // do any logic you need here
   $response = new Response();
   $response->header->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   $response->setContent(json_encode(array('host' => $host_name))); //return whatever you need
   return $response;
}
```

3) In you jQuery request you need to set the url as the generated route

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   // ajax setup 
   $.ajaxSetup({ 
      url: '{{ path('mybundle_ajaxrequest') }}', 
      type: 'POST', 
      cache: 'false' 
   });
});
```

Now you will be able to handle the returned json response in your jQuery ajax
*Keep in mind your jQuery should be in a template file (twig template file)*

Comment: Thats a new concept for me, thanks for the pointers and your all your work. I'll try to implement it in my project.

Comment: @Liam I hope you got the concept; because this the way we can create ajax request in Symfony project; let us know if you have any question. Take a look at this for more info: http://symfony2forum.org/threads/5-Using-Symfony2-jQuery-and-Ajax

Comment: But use doctrine and no mysql_* functions. If you don't want to create entities, use at least the Doctrine DBAL layer.